# This plant is growing in my garden, and it might be lettuce

Tags: identification, vegetables, leaf-vegetables, leafy-vegetables

I found this plant in my garden, and it might be a lettuce. It came a few weeks ago, and I'm not sure if it is edible.

Image:
[image: 1]

Update: This plant went into new formation:
[image]

2nd Update: The flowers finally came! The flower's color is purple. The image below shows what it is like. I got a more accurate picture of what the flowers look like.
[image: More Accurate flower]

Comment: It also looks like endive (*Cichorium endivia* var. crispum)

Comment: Is the plant edible?

Comment: Endives is edible, but better wait until it is as big as in the store, so you know for sure that it is endives.

Comment: @benn, The plant is updated, so do you have an idea of what it is?

Comment: Could still be some *Cichorium*, but it doesn't look very tasty, does it? Wait for the flowers, they can give more information.

Comment: @benn, The plant has flowers, so do you have an idea of what it is?

Comment: Very hard to see the flower on your picture. Just to be clear, I am not an *Cichorium* expert here on this forum, but the first pictures reminded me of that. Maybe it's an idea to search for "Cichorium endivia flower" on google image?

Comment: I got a more accurate description of the flowers.

Comment: Do you agree that it looks like [*Cichorium endivia*?](https://worldoffloweringplants.com/cichorium-endivia-endive/)

Comment: Yes. I agree. So is it edible and can I eat it?

Comment: When I searched for "Cichorium endivia flower", the results were blue flowers. The flower in my picture is purple.

Comment: When you want to eat endive that has flowered already, please be aware that it is very bitter.

Comment: Is that same with all plants?

Comment: No only with endive and lettuce kind of plants.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!